# What is the best way to add key-value pair(s) to a JS object present in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is the best way to add new key-value pair(s) to a JS object present in an array:

```js
documents = [{ doc1: 'abc', doc2: 'def' }]
```

from another JS object

```js
documen = {opq: 'rst', uvw: 'xyz' }
```

**Option 1**: Using dot notation:

```js
documents[0].doc3 = documen.opq
documents[0].doc4 = documen.uvw
```

**Option 2**: Using spread syntax (`...`):

```js
documents[0] = {...documents[0], doc3: documen.opq, doc4: documen.uvw}
```

I tried both options and the both work. What I want to know is if there's any other better way to get the same result as above 2 options and if there's not which one of the above 2 ways is ***performance-wise better***.

Comment: There is also `Object.assign`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those options are perfectly fine. Any performance difference will be utterly negligible and thus not worth considering. The spread approach may be a bit more expensive because it has to iterate over all properties in the object to create a new object, but it doesn't matter. What's more important will be

- what you and other maintainers of the code consider readable, and
- whether the code style of the codebase accepts mutation (some do, some don't)

For example, some sorts of libraries and frameworks - like React - do not behave well when an object is mutated directly. If you happen to be using one of those, the fact that both options mutate the array would be something to keep in mind. If you aren't using anything for which mutation matters, then it doesn't matter.

Your first approach mutates one of the items in the array. Your second approach mutates the array itself, by replacing an item with a new one. If you were in the situation where you had to do this without mutating *anything*, you'd need

```
const newDocuments = documents.map((doc, i) =>
  i === 0
    ? ({ ...doc, doc3: documen.opq, doc4: documen.uvw })
    : doc
);
```

But unless you're actually in the situation where mutation is a problem worth worrying about, you may well consider your first option to be the most readable (because the performance aspect is a non-issue, and because the dot notation approach is dead simple).